# Добавление к текущему времени, время введеное пользователем

Tags: node.js, unix, datetime

У продукта должно быть время опубликования его на сайте, тут просто я использую `let now = new Date();`. Возникла проблема, продукт должен быть на сайте не мение двух часов и не более пяти дней(определяет это пользователь). Как это реализовать, чтобы пользователь ввел к примеру 1 день и в базе данных когда продукт опубликовали было `start_date = 14:00 06:02:2019`, и когда продукт закроется `end_data = 14:00 07:02:2019`?

Я подумал чтобы исполоьзовать время `unix`, нашел [unix-time](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unix-time), но как к дате опубликования добавить дату закрытия товара которую ввел пользователь?

Версия возникла:

`a` - текущая версия времени в формате `unix`;

`b` - будущая версия времени в формате `unix` веденная пользователем;

`c` - разница `b` от `a`;

`d` - сумма `a` и `c`;

Получатся что `d` будущая дата в флрмате `unix`?

Comment: Исправьте опечатки и дайте вопросу нормальное название отражающее суть проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не обязательно использовать `unix-time`. Допустим у вас в базе есть `start_date` и `end_date` типа `DateTime`.
Тогда при создании товара берем дату начала:

```
let start = new Date();
```

И дату конца (+ 1 день):

```
let end = start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1)
```

Заносим данные в бд.

Далее у вас есть скрипт (задача), которая сверяет таблицу товаров на дату окончания, как пример:

```
let now = new Date();
if (now >= end_date)
   удаляем или переносим товар в неактивные.
```

Это как пример, что бы объяснить посыл.

Comment: Суть ясна. не ясно одно мне. Товар выставлен допустем `14:00 06:02:2019`, то есть в базе данных `start_date = 14:00 06:02:2019` и активен товар до `15:00 07:02:2019`, то есть в базе данных `end_data = 15:00 07:02:2019`. Получается товар активен 1 день и 1 час. Как мне эти 1 день и 1 час вычесть?

Comment: То есть `let date = start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1)` и `let minute= start.setDate(start.getMinute() + 1)`, мне надо эти 1 день и 1 час взять как то из `15:00 07:02:2019`, а в базу данных занести `end_data = 15:00 07:02:2019`

Comment: Если вам нужно именно узнать кол-во дней, минут, то можно взять из даты начала и конца дни - `let startDay = start_date.getDate()`, `let endDay = end_date.getDate()` и вычесть `let days = endDay - startDay`, так же и с часами.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Помогла в этом мне библиотека [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment).

```
import moment from 'moment'; // подключаем библиотеку

let a = moment(); // текущее время (2019-02-06T15:41:23.455)
console.log(a);
let b = moment(req.body.end_date); // время введеное пользователем, взято е из тела (2019-02-10T17:27:19.000)
console.log(b);

let c = b.diff(a, 'hours'); // разницв в часач (Разница в 97 часах)
let d = b.diff(a, 'days'); // разница в днях (Разница в 4 дней)
console.log('Разница в ' + c + ' часах'); 
console.log('Разница в ' + d + ' дней');

console.log(moment().add(c, 'hours').format()) // добавляем к текушему времи, разницу времени(т.е. 2019-02-10T16:41:23+06:00)
```